# firebase admin sdk authentication fails locally with getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-cli

Having a local developed cloud function and started it locally via:

> firebase emulators:start

The cloud function is here:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');

 admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
   databaseURL:"https://test1-xxx.firebaseio.com",
 });
```

I get:

```
 FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND".
     at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/dgang/study/test/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
     at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/dgang/study/test/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
     at new FirebaseAppError (/Users/dgang/study/test/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
     at /Users/dgang/study/test/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:121:23
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5) {    errorInfo: {
     code: 'app/invalid-credential',
     message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via ' +
       'the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google ' +
       'OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error ' +
       'fetching access token: Error while making request: ' +
       'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error ' +
       'code: ENOTFOUND".'    },    codePrefix: 'app'  }
```

I defined GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as needed but this does not help.

I tried to google the issue but without avail.

What needs to be fixed here?

Update:

When i require the service account explicitely it works:

```
var serviceAccount = require("service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL:"https://test1-xxx.firebaseio.com",
  });
```

but this is a dangerous option

Comment: What do you mean it’s dangerous? If you’re using some form of version control, you can add the service account JSON file to the provider’s ignore file (typically `.gitignore`). It also appears that you haven’t read the getting started guide for running functions locally: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator (especially the “set up admin credentials” section)

Comment: Hi, I read this guide and sorry if i missed something. As i mentioned i defined GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. This should have given the same effect as in the sandcase env. What specifically did i miss?

Comment: Are you sure you mentioned that? It doesn’t appear to be in your question.

Comment: editing. sorry.

Comment: Have you double-checked if the environment variable pointing to the exact location of the service account is correct?

Comment: yes i checked by ls $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS